# htaccess: add trailing slash to specific case only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

quick question regarding my .htaccess file

I want to forward https://myurl.com/en to https://myurl.com/en/ with a trailing slash.

This is my try so far.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.en[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always activate [DirectorySlash](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectorySlash) for a specific location:

```
<Location "/en">
  DirectorySlash On
  FallbackResource /index.php
</Location>
```

I didn't spend that much time on this issue, but you want to read the warning about it in the link above. Or you can use the alternative solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

If problems with relative urls for images etc. try adding the following to your page header:

```
<head>
 <base href="/" />
<head>
```

Restart apache in order for the changes to take effect. If WordPress is used pay attention to the order of execution. **All the redirect rules must be located before routing rules. The WordPress rules route everything to index.php.**

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this, I tried the 2nd snippet you shared, but unfortunately also without success. See my comment above whre I also tried the solution of @Googlian with this: blob:https://imgur.com/db07147e-6fb5-43b9-acc1-3f91ae2ab86f

I cleared the cache and even tried in different browsers in incognito windows.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example, I missed some obvious things. It is hardcoded to explicitly use "/en" thus ignoring "/path/en".

Comment: Unfortunately still not taking effect. See the entire htaccess file: https://jsfiddle.net/tuza7s49/

Comment: I added solution to your problem in the update. WP section must be last, see https://jsfiddle.net/x3n50e8p/

Answer (score 0):

**To ensure all URLs have a trailing slash.**

The below rule will forward `https://myurl.com/en` to `https://myurl.com/en/` with a trailing slash at the end.

> https://myurl.com/en to https://myurl.com/en/

**Setting trailing slash globally for all of your URLs in your domain name.**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myurl.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

**The below rule is applicable only for a specific URL segment:**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^en$ /en/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

**Clear the browser cache**

Once you made any changes in your `.htaccess` file, you have to clear your browser cache before try it again or open through a new incognito browsing mode to test your changes, most of the modern browsers usually cache the webpage so you cannot see the action unless you cleared the browser cache.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, but this is not taking effect for me! I tried the second snippet you shared. It does not redirect from en to en/ for me. This is what I tried: blob:https://imgur.com/db07147e-6fb5-43b9-acc1-3f91ae2ab86f

Comment: Sure, I quickly used jsfiddle for this and pasted the entire .htaccess file into the html tab: https://jsfiddle.net/b0suL6md/